# Magento layout xml replace phtml file

Tags: layout, xml

i am writing my extension and i have troubles in my extension layout xml file. I need override my_theme/catalog/product/list.phtml to my_theme/myextension/mylist.phtml

I am trying to write the next code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <catalog_category_layered>
         <reference name="catalog_product_list">
             <action method="setTemplate">
                 <template>myextension/mylist.phtml</template>
             </action>
         </reference>
     </catalog_category_layered>
 </layout>
```

But this no working. Help me please

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE! Unfortunately as it stands this question is vague and requires a lot more information for us to help you. Please provide all relevant code as well as the desired outcome/effect that you're looking to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you check your question, after posting, if you don't see the code, we don't see the code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To call methods on a block, you have to make sure two things:

1. the block exists, when you try to call a method on it.
2. you use the name of the block.

e.g. here:

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            ...
```

The name is `product_list` not `catalog_product_list`. And in the layered_navigation block it is `product_list` too, so change the reference and it should work

Comment: Still I have a doubt. We need to ensure the extension should load after `Mage_Catalog` loads right ? Otherwise there would be a chance to override again our custom template. Since `Mage_Catalog` is setting default template for this block. What would you think ? Am I right ?

Comment: You have to be sure, that the block exists and that there is no other `setTemplate` call after yours but I think this i not the case. The block is created, the template set and then your `layout.xml` is parsed. So as long as you have no problems, don't think about it ;-)

Comment: I didn't see the `layout.xml` mentioning. He mentioned just `layout xml`. I "parsed" it in a general sense. What I understood from that is he has a layout xml file for his extension. It may be `layout.xml` or his own `extension_layout.xml`. That is why I asked. what if he has custom layout file for his extension? Does my question has any relevance in that case ?

Comment: ah ok. Just have a look into the file whether he has an `<action>` node in it. if yes, you can `<depend>` on his module, then your layout.xml is parsed after his. But only, if you use the same or a later update handle like `catalog_category_default` if you use an earlier one, you can't do anything except to change the handle

Comment: `if yes, you can <depend> on his module, then your layout.xml is parsed after his`. I dint get this point. I am not talking about my extension. I only talking about the extension that is in question. Suppose extension contains a frontend layout definition in its config file. Let the file mentioned be `foo.xml`. I think he can use this layout file for setting template for product-list block. In that case, my question has any relevance ?

Comment: "If any other module changes the template, how can I change it?" - You change it the normal way with setTemplate, and make sure, your call is after theirs. And to be sure, you can depend on the module, so you layout file is parsed after. --- I'm not sure, wether I got your point.